# How is std::string::size() implemented?

Tags: c++, string

```
cout << sizeof(std::string) << endl;
```

The result is 8 on my 64-bit machine, which is the same as `sizeof(char*)`, so I am assuming the string class stores only the `char*`. How, then, is the size function implemented?  Is it using `strlen` (since it is not storing the actual size or the pointer to the ending byte)?

On [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size), it shows the size function has a constant time-complexity, so I am confused.  And on [another page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3770781/why-is-sizeofstring-32) someone has a larger string size.

I am using GCC 4.7.1 on Fedora 64 bit.

Comment: `<string>` should be header-only, so you could just take a look...

Comment: You didn't specify what `string` is. Do you mean `std::string` from `<string>`?

Comment: Conceivably, `std::string` could store a pointer to a single block of memory that holds its length followed by actual characters.

Comment: The only non-static member I found in the header is: `mutable _Alloc_hider _M_dataplus;`, and `_Alloc_hider` seems to have only a `char*`member.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Or (as Microsoft has defined `BSTR`) a pointer to the actual characters, prefixed by their length. I.e. `*((size_t*)ptr - 1)`. That means `.size()` needs a fixed offset and `operator[]` a variable one, but with your proposal `operator[]` needs two offsets. That's more expensive on x86 IIRC.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There could be many explanations for that. Just because `std::string` happens to store a pointer and nothing else does not mean that this is necessarily `char *` pointer to the controlled sequence. Why did you jump to that conclusion?

It could easily turn out that your `std::string` is a PImpl-style wrapper for a pointer to some internal object that stores all internal household data, including the `char *` pointer, the length and whatever else is necessary. That way the internal object can be arbitrarily large, without having any effect on the size of `std::string` itself. For example, in order to facilitate fast reference-counted copying, in some implementations `std::string` might be implemented similarly to `std::shared_ptr`. I.e. `std::string` in that case would essentially become something like `std::shared_ptr<std::string_impl>` with added copy-on-write semantics.

The target "string implementation" object might even use "struct hack"-style approach to store the actual string, meaning that instead of storing `char *` pointer it might embed the entire string into itself at the end.

Answer (score 7):

Looking at the [doxygen docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/latest-doxygen/a01006_source.html#l00437) for libstdc++:

```
_CharT* _M_p; // The actual data
```

Assuming `std::basic_string<char>`, `_M_p` is a `char*` pointer to the actual data, so that is why you are getting `8`.

It even says:

> Where the _M_p points to the first character in the string, and you
>   cast it to a pointer-to-_Rep and subtract 1 to get a pointer to the
>   header.

So, it hides a pointer to the actual representation (capacity, length, etc.) in a block of memory right before where the string data is stored.

Then, there is the following member function to get to the representation:

```
Rep* _M_rep() const
{ return &((reinterpret_cast<_Rep*> (_M_data()))[-1]); }
```

and then they call it like this `_M_rep()->_M_length;` to get the `size` for example.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that std::string is char* is wrong. Here is one of q few possible implementations with sizeof(std::string)==sizeof(char*):

```
struct std::string
{
    string_implementation
    {
        size_t size;
        size_t buffer_size;
        char_traits whatever;
        char *buffer; // Here is your actual string!
    };

    string_implementation *ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::string` is a `typdef` for `std::basic_string<char>`, and `basic_string` is defined (on my machine) in file `/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/basic_string.h`. There's a lot of indirection in that file, but roughly speeking `std::string` stores a pointer to actual data

```
// Use empty-base optimization: http://www.cantrip.org/emptyopt.html
      struct _Alloc_hider : _Alloc
      {
    _Alloc_hider(_CharT* __dat, const _Alloc& __a)
    : _Alloc(__a), _M_p(__dat) { }

    _CharT* _M_p; // The actual data.
      };
```

and this is why you observed such behavior. This pointer might might be casted to obtain pointer to structure that describes the well-known string properties (located just in front of actual data):

```
  struct _Rep_base
  {
size_type       _M_length;
size_type       _M_capacity;
_Atomic_word        _M_refcount;
  };

_Rep* _M_rep() const
      { return &((reinterpret_cast<_Rep*> (_M_data()))[-1]); }
```