# what does C do if argv is a type other than char **

Tags: c, command-line, arguments

I was messing around in C, and decided it'd be cool to try changing up the type of argv from char * to int, just to see what would happen. I wrote this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, int  argv )
{
        printf("arg is %d \n", argv);
}
```

I get really weird output from this program. Whenever I run it, with whatever arguments I run it with, it seems to just spit back random numbers at me. Here is the output:

```
[14:30:00][maksim]~/learnProg/cDance$ ./dink
arg is -2058142376 
[14:30:01][maksim]~/learnProg/cDance$ ./dink 2141
arg is 2111473256 
[14:30:04][maksim]~/learnProg/cDance$ ./dink 2141
arg is -8005928
```

(the program is called dink). Whats going on? What does C do when it compiles this? What would happen if I used data types other than int, like a double or a structure or whatever?

Comment: shouldn't `int argv` be `char ** argv`? http://ideone.com/MENAsZ

Comment: Try reading the question again.

Comment: try to cast it to (char **) and access its content

Comment: `argv` is `char **` so if you pass as `int` you have to cast it back. Messing with standard function signatures will not give you expected results :)

Comment: Why playing around, it C generally pointer to character string do not convert easilly, you might opt for perl or another language that does some magic for you.

Comment: Im playing around from academic interest

Comment: Why don't you try another "cool things" like using system calls in weird ways or messing up bits or something else and then ask what C does in this cases?

Comment: I do that too..studying how a system behaves in strange scenarios is a good way to become a better programmer. why is everyone so angry?

Comment: Not sure why the downvotes.  It's a pretty good question, OP is pretty clear that they know how to write a basic C program, and as a somewhat experienced C developer I'm not sure how the compiler or linker handles this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others noted, the behavior is undefined (so anything might happen).

Let's look at three "typical" behaviors though.  Three common ways to pass arguments are:

- on a stack
- in general purpose registers
- in special purpose registers

Intel x86 systems mostly use the first method (but sometimes the second or third).  MIPS-based processors mostly use the second.

If a system uses one or more stacks, the usual calling method is:

- in the caller (some OS-supplied routine that calls `main`), push arguments, typically right to left, i.e., in reverse order.  Stack pushes usually (but not always) look like `*--sp = value;` in C, with the stack pointer(s) descending from some high address.
- make the call into the target function (`main`)
- in the target function, retrieve parameters off "the stack" or "the parameter stack" or "the current thread stack" or whatever the system uses.  Because they were pushed in reverse order, they are at addresses like `sp[0]`, `sp[1]`, etc.  If the calling mechanism uses the same stack as the parameter-passing mechanism, the indexes may start at 1 or 2 or even more (`sp[2]` being the first argument, for instance, and `sp[3]` being the second).

In this case, `argc` will probably come out correct but `argv` will mis-interpret whatever the caller pushed, producing a strange-looking `int`.  If the underlying system is sufficiently fancy (checking types), it might detect that the caller pushed a value of type `char **` but you're accessing one of type `int`, and give you some kind of run-time error.  Most systems simple prefer to give you the wrong answer as fast as possible, though, skipping the type-checking.  So you'll get a strange-looking `int`, but it will actually be based (at least in part—see below) off the actual pointer value the caller tried to pass.

If the system uses general purpose registers (instead of, or prior to, using a stack—systems using GPRs often fall back on stacks if you use many parameters, and sometimes use them for all variadic functions, i.e., those using the `<stdarg.h>` facilities), then the calling method looks more like this:

- in the caller, move arguments (`int argc` value and `char **argv` value) into the first two argument registers (e.g., `%o0` and `%o1` on SPARC, or `$a0` and `$a1` on MIPS).
- make the call to the target function
- in the target function, access the values from the argument registers

In this case, the code generally behaves the same as on the stack-based system.  It just runs faster, since arguments-in-registers tend to need fewer CPU cycles than arguments-in-memory.  (This is why some Intel compilers will sometimes pass an argument or two in registers.)

If the system uses special purpose registers, though, we get a new apparent behavior.  Let's say that floating point values go in `f` registers (true on some SPARC systems; x86 has the MMX and SSE registers instead); pointer values go in `a` registers (a la 680x0 CPUs); and integer values go in `d` registers (680x0, again—although in practice most 680x0 systems just use "the stack", but let's assume we have one that uses registers).  This time, the thing calling `main` needs to pass one integer, `argc`, and one pointer, `argv`, so it does this:

- move integer argument `argc` into data register `d0`
- move pointer argument `argv` into pointer register `a0`
- call `main`

Now, in `main()`, you told the compiler to expect two *integer* arguments, which would arrive in registers `d0` and `d1` respectively.  What's in CPU register `d1`?  Who knows, the thing that called `main` did not set it just before the call.  It has whatever value it has, from whoever last stuck some value in it.  The value is no longer associated with the intended `argv`, since that's in register `a0`.

Now, even if you have a stack or GPR-based calling system, there's another few wrinkles to consider:

- What if pointers are 64 bits and plain `int`s are only 32 bits?  In this case, the caller pushes a 64-bit value, or writes a 64-bit value into the parameter-register; but `main` looks only at 32 bits.  You'll see half of what was actually given.
- What if pointers are 32 bits and plain `int`s are 64 bits?  That's an unusual implementation, to be sure, but now you'll be looking at all 64 bits of a value that only supplied 32.  The "extra" 32 bits might be all zero (this would be typical for parameters in GPRs), or might be 32 bits of some unrelated value, similar to the case of inspecting register `d1` when `main`'s caller filled in register `a0`.
- And of course, there's nothing that says 32 and 64 bits are the only possible sizes.  On IBM AS/400 systems, pointers are a whopping 128 bits long (16 byte tagged pointers), and there is extensive run-time type-checking.  These machines work on making sure the code is correct, not merely fast.

---

There's one other noteworthy possibility.  If you build similar C++ code (with a function other than `main`), it generally fails to link.  The reason is that C++ compilers often use a technique called "name mangling" to handle overloaded functions.  A function named `f` that takes one `int` and one `char **` argument and returns `int` produces the link-time symbol `Z1fiPPC`.  A function named `f` that takes two `int`s and returns `int` produces the link-time symbol `Z1fii` instead.  I haven't seen C compilers that do this, but they *could* do it.  In this case, the compiler would check, at link time, whether your program defined `Z4mainippC`—`int main(int, char **)`—and if so, link in the caller that provides those arguments; or it would check for `Z4mainv`—`int main(void)`—and in that case link in the caller that provides no arguments.  If neither function is found, the linker could detect that you wrote an incorrect `main` and not produce an executable at all!

Comment: You sound like someone who has written a compiler. :-)

Comment: @Jens: well, "worked on" (more than one), not quite "written" ... compilers these days are just too big. :-)

Answer (score 3):

You'll get undefined behavior, which means it's legitimate for *anything* to happen.  `main` must be declared as:

```
int main(void)
```

or as:

```
int main(int arg, char** argv)
```

or as some form specified by your implementation.

From section J.2 of the ISO C99 standard:

> The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances:
>
> ...
>
> - A program in a hosted environment does not define a function named `main` using one of the specified forms (5.1.2.2.1).

Comment: Even though this may be the least informative answer, it is in a way the most correct. In the general case, across architectures, implementations, and versions, this is all you can say. The fact that we can speculate about why your compiler did what it did doesn't change the fundamental truth that what you are seeing is really just "garbage in, garbage out".

Comment: "or in some other implementation-defined manner." If the implementation documents it, `struct { int foo, bar; double quux; unsigned baz:3; } main(double argc, void*** argv)` is legit. Okay, no known implementation documents _that_ signature, but `int main(int argc, char **argv, char **envp)` is not unheard-of.

Answer (score 2):

`argv` is passed to your program as a pointer to an array of pointers to strings.

If lie and you tell the compiler that it's an `int`, the bytes of the pointer will be interpreted as an `int`, and you'll get a memory address.  (on a 64-bit system, you'll probably get a crash)

If you pretend that it's a `float`, the compiler will probably interpret those bytes / bits as an IEE-754-encoded floating-point value, resulting in a differently weird number.  (what exactly happens depends on the calling convention)

If you pretend that it's any type which is not the same width as a pointer, you will probably crash.

### The moral of the story is

C does exactly what you tell it to.  It is up to you to tell it how to interpret things.

Comment: Didn't You mean `argv` in the first line?

Comment: Many C implementations pass pointers in the same places as `int` arguments, but it is not unusual for floating-point arguments to be passed in different places. It is therefore incorrect to state that an argument passed by a caller who views it as a pointer but received by a routine that views it as an `int` will interpret the bytes of the pointer as a floating-point value. The bytes in the location where a floating-point value is passed will generally be completely unrelated to the pointer.

Comment: Additionally, even in implementations that pass `int` arguments in the same locations as pointer arguments, the locations of bytes passed for a pointer do not necessarily correspond to the locations for an `int`, since size mismatches (e.g., 32-bit `int`, and 64-bit pointer) can alter where specific arguments are passed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I mentioned differences in pointer-size. Why would floats be passed differently? To better work with the FPU?

Comment: @SLaks: Yes, that is a common reason to pass floating-point values differently. It takes time to move values from floating-point registers to general registers or to memory, and it takes time to move them back. So it is a waste to require callers to move the data instead of leaving it in the registers where it often already is and where it is likely to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Well...

Argv is an array. In C, arrays are simply pointers. Pointers are internally just integers for memory locations. So, the numbers you saw are locations in memory. (I'm guessing the negatives are because it's not unsigned)

Comment: Arrays are not simply pointers. Pointers may or may not be integers for memory locations; that is up to each C implementation.

Comment: Arrays and pointers are indeed different—but a formal parameter, like `argv` in main, if declared with array type, actually declares a pointer.  (In C99, the new extra meaning of the `static` keyword makes a bit of mess of the old type-rewrite rule, in the name of optimization, but one can mostly ignore that.)

Answer (score 0):

The C main() functions receives an integer for the argument count and a pointer to an array of char.

Your output is simply the memory address which this pointer contains.
If you cast it to other variable types, they will also contain "rubbish".

Under normal circumstances, it should be avoided to cast pointers, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first understand what exactly `argv` is.

Consider the standard `main()` format. It is `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`
Here `argv` is an array of character pointers. Since name of an array is a constant pointer to it's first member, we will say `argv` is a pointer to it's first member. i.e. `argv` is pointer to character pointer.

Now please note name doesn't matter here. It can be anything beside `argv`. What matters is second argument to `main()` is a pointer to character pointer. i.e. The second argument is pointer to pointer to character.

So when program starts execution, a memory address is passed as a second argument to `main()` which is an address of another pointer. And that 'another' pointer is a memory address of very first character of very first argument. And that argument happens to be program's name.

So when you say `int main(int argc, int  argv )` you are casting an address in `int` value. If `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int *)` then that's not a problem at all. The value won't be demoted in that case.

Now when you say `printf("arg is %d \n", argv);` you are simply printing that address. That's it! No matter what are your arguments given to a program that address is a random value. That's why you are getting the random no.s which are actually the addresses of first member of `argv` array. i.e. The no. printed is an address of program name which in turn is an address of it's first char. (Since program name is again an array so is a constant pointer to it's first member. i.e. the very first character)

To verify this add this line to you code snippet:

```
printf("%c\n", **(char **)argv);
```

You will see `.` being printed which was indeed the very first character of very first argument `./dink`

Answer (score 0):

I don't disagree with most of the other answers and, as jamesdlin noted, C99 specifies the behavior as undefined if `main` is not declared properly. I think then your question becomes about what is this so-called undefined behavior. I say "so-called undefined behavior" because it is in fact defined very precisely as part of a platform/system Application Binary Interface (ABI). While the ABI may not specifically address the situation you pose with passing a pointer as an `int` but it does define how arguments are passed and so a little research will reveal exactly what happens in your particular scenario.

Since the ABI answers all of the questions about "what happens if I pass this as an int, double, or structure", your next question might be "what is the ABI for my system". The ABI is system/platform specific, it could be different between Windows and Linux, between PowerPC and X86, between different compilers, and even between different versions of a compiler. You didn't provide the necessary platform/system information to answer the "which ABI" question but, even if you had provided it, I have no intentions of answering it since research would be required on my part (I'm no expert). Besides, this is your experiment so it will be a good learning experience for you to research and understand the ABI of your system.

There is a lot of good information out there, including a question asking [what is the ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171177/what-is-application-binary-interface-abi), a brief overview of the [Linux ABI](http://kernelnewbies.org/ABI) and, of course, the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). The ABI question provides a link to the System V ABI PDF and that very possibly covers your system ABI so might be the best place to start.

To summarize, your experiment results in undefined behavior according to C99 but the actual behavior is defined by the system ABI but the system ABI is, well, system-specific. In other words, C99 does not specify the behavior in your experiment because it is system-specific behavior that is outside of C99. The system-specific ABI, on the other hand, does define the behavior as part of the definition of how arguments are passed. By understanding your system's ABI you will be able to understand (i.e. *define*) the behavior you are seeing. Most likely this definition will be somewhat unimpressive, for example, the `int` argument and pointer argument are not compatible so what you receive as the `int` argument truly is random garbage that happens to reside in a certain register or memory location. Or it could be the upper or lower 32bits of a 64bit pointer.