# Is there a standard way to reconstruct lowered struct function arguments?

Tags: c, clang, llvm, llvm-ir, abi

I have a structure type:

```
typedef struct boundptr {
  uint8_t *ptr;
  size_t size;
} boundptr;
```

and I want to catch all the arguments of a function of that type. E.g. in this function:

```
boundptr sample_function_stub(boundptr lp, boundptr lp2);
```

On my 64bit machine, Clang translates that signature to:

```
define { i8*, i64 } @sample_function_stub(i8* %lp.coerce0, i64 %lp.coerce1, i8* %lp2.coerce0, i64 %lp2.coerce1) #0 {
```

### Question:

Is there a better way to reconstruct such arguments?

Is it possible to forbid such argument lowering, while keeping the same ABI for external calls?

### Some more context:

So in the LLVM IR, I guess, according to the platform ABI, the compiler broke down the structure into separate fields (which is not the worst case, see [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22776391/why-does-clang-coerce-struct-parameters-to-ints)). BTW, it reconstructs the original two parameters `lp` and `lp2` later in the function body.

Now for my analysis, I want to get those two parameters `lp` and `lp2` in full, out of these 4(`lp.coerce0`, `lp.coerce1`, `lp2.coerce0` and `lp2.coerce1`). In this case, I probably can rely on the names (`.coerce0` means first field, `.coerce1` - second).

I do not like this approach:

- I am not sure, that Clang with keep this convention in later versions
- It certainly depends on the ABI, so there may be a different breakdown on another platform.

On the other side, I can not use the reconstruction code in the beginning of the function, because I may confuse it with some user code for a local variable.

---

I use Clang `3.4.2` based on LLVM `3.4.2` for target `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`.

P.S. Here is [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22776391/why-does-clang-coerce-struct-parameters-to-ints), showing how wildly Clang can mess up with function arguments.

Comment: What is your **actual** problem??

Comment: @Olaf, I need to dump the value stored by this address during llvm-IR interpretation, and I need to know the size of that value while dealing with "`void*` polymorphism"

Comment: What do you mean with "`void *` polymorphism"? Sorry, but it is still not clear why you need that. The question somehow has the haut-gout of an XY-problem. AFAIK the IR does not keep all information of compound datatypes - why should it, as it is some more abstract Assembler language.

Comment: I mean: I have a family of functions that operate on pointers to unspecified type. I interpret the LLVM IR, and I need to dump the values (memory chunks) that they are passing around. And IR does keep the datatype definitions, in this case it's: `%struct.boundptr = type { i8*, i64 }`

Comment: ... a way to know the size is to systematically pass it along with each pointer. For that I have a `boundptr` structure, but now Clang breaks it apart. I want to fix that.

Comment: "unspecified type" is not possible in C. even `void` is a type for pointers. However, your functions actually **do** know about the types. However, without more details, it is not possible to recommend a better and more portable approach. From the information given, it sounds like a problematic design. Anyway, I would think about a C-ish way and not rely on compiler details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101904/discussion-between-necto-and-olaf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are compiling not with `O0`. AFAIK, clang will reassemble the original type when you are not optimizing your code. Clang breaks down your structure to pass them through registers (at least on x86) to the called function. As you said, this depends on the ABI used.

Here is a dummy example from your use case:

```
#include <cstddef>

typedef struct boundptr {
  void *ptr;
  size_t size;
} boundptr;

boundptr foo(boundptr ptr1, boundptr ptr2) { return {ptr1.ptr, ptr2.size}; }

int main() {
  boundptr p1, p2;
  boundptr p3 = foo(p1, p2);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling it with `clang -O0 -std=c++11 -emit-llvm -S -c test.cpp` generates `foo`:

```
define { i8*, i64 } @_Z3foo8boundptrS_(i8* %ptr1.coerce0, i64 %ptr1.coerce1, i8* %ptr2.coerce0, i64 %ptr2.coerce1) #0 {
  %1 = alloca %struct.boundptr, align 8
  %ptr1 = alloca %struct.boundptr, align 8
  %ptr2 = alloca %struct.boundptr, align 8
  %2 = bitcast %struct.boundptr* %ptr1 to { i8*, i64 }*
  %3 = getelementptr { i8*, i64 }, { i8*, i64 }* %2, i32 0, i32 0
  store i8** %ptr1.coerce0, i8** %3
  %4 = getelementptr { i8*, i64 }, { i8*, i64 }* %2, i32 0, i32 1
  store i64 %ptr1.coerce1, i64* %4
  %5 = bitcast %struct.boundptr* %ptr2 to { i8*, i64 }*
  %6 = getelementptr { i8*, i64 }, { i8*, i64 }* %5, i32 0, i32 0
  store i8** %ptr2.coerce0, i8** %6
  %7 = getelementptr { i8**, i64 }, { i8**, i64 }* %5, i32 0, i32 1
  store i64 %ptr2.coerce1, i64* %7
  %8 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.boundptr, %struct.boundptr* %1, i32 0, i32 0
  %9 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.boundptr, %struct.boundptr* %ptr1, i32 0, i32 0
  %10 = load i8*, i8** %9, align 8
  store i8* %10, i8** %8, align 8
  %11 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.boundptr, %struct.boundptr* %1, i32 0, i32 1
  %12 = getelementptr inbounds %struct.boundptr, %struct.boundptr* %ptr2, i32 0, i32 1
  %13 = load i64, i64* %12, align 8
  store i64 %13, i64* %11, align 8
  %14 = bitcast %struct.boundptr* %1 to { i8*, i64 }*
  %15 = load { i8*, i64 }, { i8*, i64 }* %14, align 8
  ret { i8*, i64 } %15
}
```

`boundptr` is reconstructed on the called function stack (this also depends on the used calling convention).

Now to find out which of the `boundptr` are your parameters you can do the following:

1. Visit each `alloca` inst in your pass and follow its users.
2. Follow the casts of the `alloca` as well as GEP instructions to find the
   store instructions on the `boundptr`.
3. Inspect the value to be stored. If they are your function arguments and match types and names you have found your reassembled `boundptr`.

Of course you can do it the other way around starting from the functions arguments.

Is this future proof? No definitively not. Clang/LLVM is not designed to keep backward compatibility. For the compatibility the ABI is important.

Drawback: You have to get your pass into the optimizer really early after code generation. Even `01` will remove these stack allocations of `boundptr`. So you have to modify your `clang` to execute your pass during optimization and you cannot make it a standalone pass (e.g., used by `opt`).

**A better solution:** 
Since clang has to be modified somehow, you can add metadata identifying parameters of your `boundptr` type. So you can "pack" the fragments of your `boundptr` together to identify them as `boundptr`. This would survive the optimizer.