# What is CPP_ABI_SUPPORT for?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

`TObject` has 3 (empty and undocumented) methods called CPP_ABI_1 through 3.

```
type
  TObject = class
  ...
  {$IFDEF CPP_ABI_SUPPORT}
    procedure CPP_ABI_1; virtual;
    procedure CPP_ABI_2; virtual;
    procedure CPP_ABI_3; virtual;
  {$ENDIF !CPP_ABI_SUPPORT}
  ...
```

What purpose do these methods serve and what would be a possible use case for these methods?

Comment: Looking in System.pas (in XE8) where `CPP_ABI_SUPPORT` is defined, there's a comment: `C++ ABI support a'la the Itanium C++ ABI.`

Comment: I searched numerous RTL and FMX units for any implementation of these and could not find anything. Perhaps it's something Emba's planning on implementing soon.

Comment: Just throwing it out there, might help: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171177/what-is-application-binary-interface-abi)

Comment: Presumably these methods are used to make C++ and Delphi object layouts binary compatible. But quite what combination of compilers this is relevant to I don't know. And when, or even whether, it is used I also do not know. Anyone with access to all the compilers could check to see if these methods are ever included.