# Why g++ with -O3 segfault with the following LLVM library code

Tags: c++, c++11, clang, llvm

So I want to use the `llvm::Twine` string chunk class.

I have the following sample:

```
#include <llvm/ADT/Twine.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  llvm::Twine twine1 = llvm::Twine("aaaa") + "bbbb" + "cccc" + "dddd";
  llvm::Twine twine2 = llvm::Twine(twine1) + "dddd" + "eeee";
  std::cout << twine1.str() << std::endl;
  std::cout << twine2.str() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

It runs with `clang++` with `-O3` and `g++` with `-O0` but segfault with `g++` with `-O3`. I tried this code parts different versions of clang library from 3.4-3.9 and tried with `g++ 4.8.4`, `g++ 4.8.5` and `mingw-5.3.0`.

You need the llvm library and link the code  with `-lLLVMSupport -lLLVMCore` and the others from `llvm-config --ldflags`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Twine documentation](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1Twine.html#details):

> A Twine is not intended for use directly and should not be stored, its
>   implementation relies on the ability to store pointers to temporary
>   stack objects which may be deallocated at the end of a statement.
>   Twines should only be used accepted as const references in arguments,
>   when an API wishes to accept possibly-concatenated strings.

In the other words, Twine object doesn't own its parts, so they are destroyed at the end of statement.

A correct usage would be:

```
#include <llvm/ADT/Twine.h>
#include <iostream>

void bar(const llvm::Twine& twine1, const llvm::Twine2& twine2){
    std::cout << twine1.str() << std::endl;
    std::cout << twine2.str() << std::endl;
}

void foo(const llvm::Twine& twine1){
    bar(twine1, twine1 + "dddd" + "eeee");
}

int main()
{
  foo(llvm::Twine("aaaa") + "bbbb" + "cccc" + "dddd");

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are attempting to compile some code with `gcc`, and link it with libraries that were built with a different compiler; namely `llvm`.

Different compilers will often use different [internal ABI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171177/what-is-application-binary-interface-abi)s. Generally, code compiled by one C++ compiler cannot be linked with code that was built a different compiler, unless there's an explicit ABI compatibility guarantee. TMK, there is none, between gcc and llvm. Even though the actual link might succeed, the results will not have a defined behavior.

In fact, code built by one version of gcc will often not be linkable with code built with a different version of gcc (many versions of gcc do have certain ABI compatibility guarantees, but not with every other version of gcc).

Comment: I compiled the llvm library with gcc.

Comment: Did you compile every library you linked with, with the same version of gcc?

Comment: Yes, but this simple sample only use llvm

Comment: You stated something different in your question: you stated that multiple libraries need to be linked with. In any case, the next step would be to verify that llvm libraries are explicitly documented as being compilable with gcc. Since they are a part of the llvm infrastructure and stack, unless its stated somewhere that they can be compiled and used with gcc, I would not assume that to be true.

Comment: Thaks, I will double check these things. The other libraries is pthread, -ldl, libterm and some other generic one.

Comment: Those are C libraries, and they would not be an issue.