# How to interpret naming convention in PyPi package name

Tags: python, pypi, python-wheel

That's what can be found in lots of packages such as this one: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip

> pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

how to interpret this naming convention?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The naming format can be found under [filename convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#file-name-convention) in PEP 427:

```
{distribution}-{version}(-{build tag})?-{python tag}-{abi tag}-{platform tag}.whl
```

In this case:

`pip-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl` is the version 9.0.1 build of the pip package, compatible with both Python 2 and 3, with no ABI - [Application Binary Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2171177/what-is-application-binary-interface-abi) (pure Python), and compatible with any CPU architecture.

Comment: So it means that `py2.py3` is python tag and not an extension suffix. Interesting!

Comment: @IliaSidorenko see [PEP-425](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0425/).