# What are the meaning of whl file names for pycuda installation?

Tags: python, pycuda

[https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pycuda](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pycuda)

For instance, pycuda‑2021.1+cuda114‑cp37‑cp37m‑win_amd64.whl

I guess the cuda114 means that I have to install CUDA 11.4 in my computer(which means that I have to delete the current 11.5 if I want to install this specific file), and the last amd64 means that it is for 64bit windows. But what are the rest of them? How do I check whether my computer meets the requirement of "cp37-cp37m"?

Comment: I think this could mean cpython version 3.7

Comment: The first cp37 means that it was built with CPython 3.7. The second cp37m, I don't know.

Comment: It is a convention, not specific to pycuda. See: [How to interpret naming convention in PyPi package name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41645540/2745495) and [What does version name 'cp27' or 'cp35' mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37023557/27454950) and the main documentation at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#file-name-convention