# Swift version embedded in external Framework

Tags: ios, swift

A third part company has provide me a Framework.
I would like to check the swift version embedded in the framework (2.2, 2.3 or 3.x)
The framework directory include libswift dylib files.

How to check the swift version used in the framework ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 7):

I used the `-Swift.h` Header file.

```sh
$ cat FrameworkName.framework/Headers/FrameworkName-Swift.h
```

First line is the information you need:

```c
// Generated by Apple Swift version 5.1 (swiftlang-1100.0.270.13 clang-1100.0.33.7)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `otool` to print all versions of included binaries in the framework:

```
otool -l /path/to/your/FrameworkName.framework/Versions/A/FrameworkName
```

Comment: `Load command 48
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 60
         name @rpath/libswiftCoreLocation.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 01:00:02 1970
      current version 703.0.18
compatibility version 1.0.0`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is the output for otool for 1 dylib library. How to know if swift version used is swift 2.2, swift 2.3 or swift 3 ?

Comment: in my case the path to binary was slightly different: `otool -l /path/to/your/FrameworkName.framework/FrameworkName`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Oskars answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43539248/8084934) to get the swiftlang version (in your case: 703.0.18).

Now you just have to lookup for the Swift version in the following table:

```
Swiftlang version            Swift version
-                            -
swiftlang-602.0.49.3         1.2
swiftlang-602.0.49.6         1.2
swiftlang-602.0.53.1         1.2
swiftlang-700.0.59           2.0
swiftlang-700.1.101.6        2.1
swiftlang-700.1.101.15       2.1.1
swiftlang-703.0.18.1         2.2
swiftlang-703.0.18.8         2.2
swiftlang-800.0.46.2         3.0
swiftlang-800.0.58.6         3.0.1
swiftlang-800.0.63           3.0.2
swiftlang-802.0.48           3.1
swiftlang-802.0.51           3.1
swiftlang-802.0.53           3.1
```

[Source: Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Xcode&section=20#Latest_versions)

So 703.0.18 means Swift version 2.2.

Comment: Note that otool -l did not work for me, as the framework did not have a Versions folder. I used otool -L on the binary within instead.

Answer (score 0):

If framework supports ABI[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59271017/4770877) `Module Stability` and `Library Evolution` you also can find it. From `Swift v5.1`

```
<framework.name>.framework -> Modules -> <framework.name>.swiftmodeule -> <arch>. swiftinterface
```

For example `x86_64.swiftinterface`

```
// swift-compiler-version: Apple Swift version 5.2.4 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.9 clang-1103.0.32.53)
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I go with something like:

`grep "Generated by" Carthage/Build/iOS/Alamofire.framework/Headers/Alamofire-Swift.h`