# Swift Run Time Library vs. Swift Standard Library

Tags: swift, linker, cocoapods, static-libraries, dynamic-library

In this [tutorial on how to use CocoaPods](https://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift) I am having trouble understanding the following paragraph:

> Unlike Objective-C, the standard Swift runtime libraries aren’t
>   included in iOS! This means your framework must include the necessary
>   Swift runtime libraries. As a consequence, pods written in Swift must
>   be created as dynamic frameworks. If Apple allowed Swift static
>   libraries, it would cause duplicate symbols across different libraries
>   that use the same standard runtime dependencies.

Here are my questions:

1. What exactly are the "standard Swift Runtime Libraries"? Is the [Swift Standard Library](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift) one such standard swift run time library, would a framework I write in swift be considered a swift run time library?
2. What exactly does "Swift runtime libraries are not included in iOS" mean? I guess I am having trouble inferring what "iOS" refers too.

Any additional insight, links, resources or explanations regarding this paragraph would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit:**

After reading the [runtime library wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_library) I am no longer confused about **Q1**. The following paragraph clarified this for me:

> The concept of a runtime library should not be confused with an
>   ordinary program library like that created by an application
>   programmer or delivered by a third party, nor with a dynamic library,
>   meaning a program library linked at run time. For example, the C
>   programming language requires only a minimal runtime library (commonly
>   called crt0), but defines a large standard library (called C standard
>   library) that has to be provided by each implementation.

However I am still confused about **Q2**.

Comment: Do you know what a runtime library is? What kind of answer you'll get will depends on your prior knowledge on this

Comment: Good question! I (wrongfully) thought a run time library was the compiled version of  a"program library". Seeing your question made me doubt this. So I read the [wiki article on runtime library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runtime_library)
and no longer need clarification for question 1. But am still confused about Q2. (I'll edit my question) Thanks!

Comment: Objective C has a stable (unchanging) runtime library, so it makes sense for there to be one shared copy of the library, provided by the OS (macOS/iOS), available to all applications that need it. In contrast Swift is a rapidly evolving language, which means that its runtime library undergoes vast changes between versions. Because of this, Xcode bundles in a copy of the Swift runtime library as part of each app, to ensure that a copy of the correct version (the version the app uses) of the runtime library is available to the app.

Comment: Perfect! Totally makes sense to me now!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Objective C has a stable (unchanging) runtime library, so it makes sense for there to be one shared copy of the library, provided by the OS (macOS/iOS), available to all applications that need it. In contrast Swift is a rapidly evolving language, which means that its runtime library undergoes vast changes between versions. Because of this, Xcode bundles in a copy of the Swift runtime library as part of each app, to ensure that a copy of the correct version (the version the app uses) of the runtime library is available to the app.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift Standard Library vs Swift Run Time Library**

[[Swift Standard Library]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73843146/4770877)

`Swift Run Time Library` is a part of `Swift Standard Library`

**Before** iOS v12.2 there were not `ABI`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59271017/4770877) stability on iOS level, that is why you could see a lot of frameworks(`Swift standard library`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73843146/4770877)) inside each built target

[image]

Also you are able to adjust it via `Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries`(`ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES`) for targets before iOS v12.2