# Swift foundation vs standard library?

Tags: swift, foundation

**Question**
- What is the difference between Swift Foundation and standard library?

I know they are not in the same repository. [Swift standard library](https://github.com/apple/swift/tree/master/stdlib/public/core) and [Swift Foundation](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation).

My understanding is that **Swift standard library** is low level library that are support for core data types, array, etc... written in swift. And **Swift Foundation** is for higher level which are already included common utilities codes written in swift language. But my confusion is that why are the objective-c classes like NSArray are included in **Foundation** library? Can you explain me with more details?

Comment: From your second link (emphasis added): *“This project, swift-corelibs-foundation, provides an implementation of the Foundation API for platforms **where there is no Objective-C runtime.** On macOS, iOS, and other Apple platforms, apps should use the Foundation that comes with the operating system.”*

Comment: @MartinR Sorry, I will delete the link. However, I can still asking this question right?

Comment: @LaWinKo You've missed the point. The idea is not to delete the link, the idea is that the link answers your question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To understand what's going on here, first distinguish *three* things:

- **Swift library** is the Swift native types, like String and Array.
- **Foundation** is the Cocoa Objective-C basic set of types, like NSString and NSArray and NSDate and NSData.
- Swift also contains an ***overlay* library** that shadows (without obscuring) types in the Foundation. For example, Date shadows NSDate, and Data shadows NSData. This makes the Cocoa Foundation a lot easier to use in Swift.

Note that there are two very different relations in which a Swift type can stand with respect to a Cocoa Objective-C type.

- String and Array are completely independent native Swift types. They are *bridged* to NSString and NSArray respectively, but they *exist* without Foundation.
- Data and Date are merely facades for NSData and NSDate respectively. If you import Swift but not Foundation, Data and Date are not even present.

Okay, so far so good. But this situation presents a quandary, because one would like to use Data and Date *without* the need for Foundation, in places like Linux that do not have it in the first place. Therefore, the project you have pointed to, https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation, provides a backing for Data and Date (and so on) *independent* of Foundation.
But if you are developing for iOS or MacOS you would never use it, because the real Foundation *is* present.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now. I was confused between built-in Foundation for apple OS and Foundation for linux OS.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift Standard Library**

```
NeXTSTEP -> Cocoa -> Swift Standard Library
```

[[Cocoa]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73838903/4770877)

`Swift Standard Library`:

- **describes** fundamental data types, protocols, functions... their definitions and algorithms to work with
- **implementation** - [swift/stdlib/public/](https://github.com/apple/swift/tree/main/stdlib/public)

  - `Standard library core` - [swift/stdlib/public/core/](https://github.com/apple/swift/tree/main/stdlib/public/core) - data structures and algorithms
  - `Runtime`(Swift Run Time Library) - [swift/stdlib/public/runtime/](https://github.com/apple/swift/tree/main/stdlib/public/runtime) - low level stuff which written on more low level language(C++, Objective-C) which is a layer between compiler and `Standard library core`. It responsible for `dynamism`(runtime features) - memory management, reflection...
  - `SDK Overlays` - which helps to support compatibility with Swift with Objective-C

    - `Swift Foundation` - `swift/stdlib/public/Darwin/Foundation/` -> [`swift-corelibs-foundation`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/) is a part of `SDK Overlays` which allows you to work with `Objective-C Foundation` framework from Swift codebase.

[[Binary representation]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73858936/4770877)