# Why could we use traits compiled with 2.11 from 2.12?

Tags: scala, traits

While understanding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39119831/3663882) I wrote my own example which uses a trait with scala-library version `2.11.4`:

```
trait Trace {
  def id(): Int
  def concrete(i : Int) = println(i)
}
```

from a program uses version `2.12.0-M5`.

```
object App {
  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    println("st")
    val t = new TraceImpl
    println(t.id())
    t.concrete(10)
  }

  class TraceImpl extends Trace{
    override def id(): Int = 1
  }
}
```

I expected that some exception would be thrown at runtime, but the program works fine and prints:

```
st
1
10
```

Why? Runtime implementation of traits is supposed to be changed as of version `2.12.x`?

Comment: How are you building this, precisely?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I build and run it from Intellij.

Comment: Are the files in different projects (or at least different IDEA modules)? And are you just using different `scala-library.jar` or different compiler versions?

Comment: If they are merely in different modules, IDEA may simply be smart enough to recompile `Trait`.